# function argument as a const value

Tags: c++

I was playing with different signatures and came up with following example:

```
void foo(const int a)
{
    a = 5; //error: assignment of read-only parameter 'a'
}

void foo(int a) //error: redefinition of 'void foo(int)'
{
    a = 5;
}

struct B
{
    virtual void foo(const int a) {};
};

struct D: public B
{
    void foo(int a) override {}; // fine
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
};
```

I understand that passing const by value doesn't have much sense as we're dealing with the local copy, on the other hand a signature makes a difference in the implementation.

Why then compiler completely ignores this difference for both overloading and overriding? I tested this example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/88jojGhGh with different compilers and the results seem to be consistent.

Comment: It ignores it because that's how C++ works. A `const` function parameter means that the function cannot modify its value. That's all that it is. If the `const` parameter is an `int`, the parameter is an `int`. End of story. Both `void foo(int)` and `void foo(const int)` are two functions that take a single `int` as a parameter. And you can only have one of them.

Comment: you somewhat answered your own question already. It makes no difference for the caller, but for the implementation. Overriding and overloading is for the caller. The parameter being `const` only matters for the implementation

Comment: I suspect the same applies to `volatile`.